# How to fetch data from the DB using Vue axios in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I need to fetch the **data** from the **DB** using a **query** in the controller.

I have **3 div's** in the vue template.

```
<div id="div1">0</div>
<div id="div2">0</div>
<div id="div3">0</div>
```

The value `0` should be replaced by Count(*) value from the **query**, for each div `element`.
The query should be from 2 `tables`
**Table A and
Table B**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM $tableA->project WHERE $tableB->question != null;
```

The Query results in the  3 Tables `ProjectA`, `ProjectB`, `ProjectC`  ($tableA->project = ProjectA, ProjectB, ProjectC) Where the table `ProjectA`, `ProjectB`, `ProjectC` has a  column named `1` ($tableB->question = 1 ) Which contains `Values(like 1, 2,3)` not the **EMPTY values**. The  total count of all the **Non-EMPTY Values** should be the result of the Query.

For Ex,the Table Project A has the Column like the below

**Project A**

```
1 (COLUMN)
EMPTY
EMPTY
EMPTY
1
2
EMPTY
```

**Project B**

```
1 (COLUMN)
EMPTY
EMPTY
EMPTY
1
2
EMPTY
```

The `0` in the each Div's should be replaced by Count of the values(in the col `1` in the tables, Which is total count here is 2(1,2))

1. Vue script

```
export default {

      data: function() {
            return {
              actualValue:'',
              query: ''
            }
        },
  mounted() {
      this.updateValue()
},
 updateValue: function() {

     axios.get('/api/updatedcount/',{
      query: this.query

     }).then((response) => {
               this.actualValue = response.data;
               console.log(this.actualValue);


               })
                .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
    });
 }
```

2. Routes/web.php

```
 Route::get('/updatedcount', 'someController@someMethod');
```

How to Write controller code to `fetch the count(*)` from the Query and to bind it the `div`?
Could someone please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vue provides [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) and [Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for this tasks.

Then you can use the [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) operator in one div that will create all sub-divs with the values you get (all counts for you) and whenever it changes vue will change it for you.

For this knowledge now you can make a array with your values and loop them in your divs. Change, add, update or delete them via axios calls just changing the computed property or update watcher.